# Question concerning google earth placemark balloons

Tags: styles, kml, google-earth-plugin, balloon

Does anybody know a way of styling a google earth placemark balloon differently than the original one looks like? i am not talking about the kml data i put into the balloon. i know how to style this. I am talking about the bubble itself, I would like to have it lesser rounded and with a far lesser padding. Also, i'd like to have it closer to the placemark icon. how can i realize this?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no - the basic style of the balloon is determined by the application and there is no exposed way to alter it. However, you could use image based screen overlays rather than balloons if stylistic concerns are your priority.